What did the Brisker Rav say about the Lubavitcher Rebbe?
In this answer, @Schmerel quotes the Brisker Rav as having seen a maamar from the Lubavitcher Rebbe, Rabbi M M Schneerson, and commented that the Lubavitcher Rebbe believes he is Moshiach. Here is the wording from the above answer:

As is well known, after seeing the maamer "Basi Legani" the Brisker
Rav immediately said "this person talked into himself that he is
Mosiach and we are going to ...from him in the future"
My father who was a Lubavitcher bochur in the 1950s said that back
then even in Chabad it was known that the Brisker Rav had said that
and that other Gedolim felt that way too (in general terms), but it
was vehemently denied that Chabad would ever embrace it's current
messianism focus or proclaim the rebbe to be mosiach.

Is this comment of the Brisker Rav - or any other comment regarding the Lubavitcher Rebbe - documented anywhere? I'm looking for sources, context or further details about the Brisker Rav's view.

Please don't react to this question because you are pro- or anti- Chabad. This question is not seeking to attack anyone, just looking for a source.

In the interests of darchei shalom I thought that it would be of interest to post a link to this article https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/529444/jewish/The-Rebbe-and-the-Rav.htm which looks at the warm relationship between Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneerson זצ״ל, and Rabbi Joseph Ber Soloveitchik זצ״ל, the nephew of the Brisker Rav זצ״ל

In your opening sentence it is unclear who the he in “he believes” is. When I first read it it sounded like the Brisker Rav is the believer, but the apparently negative context of the quote leads me to believe the Lubavitcher Rebbe is the believer.

Is this really about Judaism?

@mbloch - More than most of the Chabad questions on this site (eg: this one; this one, or this one).

@mbloch - While I respect your view that this is about Jewish People and not Judaism, I personally consider analysis of the Brisker Rav's perspective of anything as Torah, especially his position on something as nuanced and confusing as Chabad.

As I pointed out over there, the quote itself needs editing for clarity and grammar.

@EdwardB Note that Rabbi Yoshe Ber Soleveitchik z"l wasn't just a nephew of the Brisker Rav, he was one of his early talmidim.

@MichoelR - That's one of the reasons this quote is so interesting - the Brisker Rav's penetrating foresight to see the direction this was heading, long before the signs were in the open.

@MIchoelR - IIRC, he was a talmid of his father R' Moshe zt"l, the brother of the Brisker Rav. Are you sure he was a talmid?

R' Moshe Schuchman tells me the following: In Nefesh HaRav and other places there are incidents from when Rav Velvel was with his brother, Rav Moshe, in Chaslovitch. I don't have the timeline clear,  it may have been during the upheavel of WWI, prior to Rav Velvel succeeding his father as Rov of Brisk (in those circumstances the two great brothers worked out the famous shtickel about daled kosos due to the lack of wine). By all accounts he forged a close relationship with his nephew, the young Rav Yoshe Ber, and deeply influenced him.

@mbloch (and the other closure voters) please explain how this is not about Judaism. Rabbi A transmits theological treatise, Rabbi B reputedly comments about Rabbi A's eschatological  view thought to be revealed by theological treatise. Given the stature of the rabbis under scrutiny, questioner seeks to verify validity of report as it has ramifications for how we view this religious topic. I genuinely do not understand. Votes to close should not be used to silence questions we simply do not like or make us feel uncomfortable.

...  This relationship apparently continued years later as many of the letters printed in the back of  Chidushei Maran Riz HaLevi on Rambam are addressed to RYB, although his name was unfortunately redacted. RYB's son, Prof. Chaim, was in his great-uncle's house in Yerushalayim the Motzei Yom Kippur after his petirah, as recorded in the original Yiddish version of the magisterial hesped that RYB delivered for his uncle.

...It's well worth reading  the hesped, even the Hebrew version, which was printed as מה דודך מדוד. Here's a contemporaneous account: https://yucommentator.org/1959/12/rabbi-dr-soloveitchik-eulogizes-famed-uncle-the-brisker-rav-vol-25-issue-5/"

@Deuteronomy Second. This is clearly a dispute about the Torah between gedolim and as such clearly relevant to this site.

I have heard someone tell me this story as well but who was present for it being said? Given the relationship of the brisket Rav with chabad are you so certain this was said to begin with? Here is a small example of what I'm talking about... https://crownheights.info/something-jewish/524536/weekly-story-a-tale-of-two-mountains/

@Dude "are you so certain this was said to begin with" How would anyone be certain? He's just asking for a source to this story.

@MichoelR witnesses that were present when it was said. How many and who were they?

@Dude Well, do you have witnesses for the quote that you provided about R' Chaim Brisker? Someone told a story. Stories are stories.

There were lots of witnesses to the positive relationship between the brisker Rav and chabad Rebbeim over time. There is a single quote to suggest this suddenly broke in America and we should accept this as fact?

It didn't "suddenly break" It broke after the seventh Lubavitcher Rebbe took over. Even in Chabad itself itself it is acknowledged that the seventh Lubavitcher Rebbe  did and said things that no pervious Lubavitcher Rebbe did or said such type things .

@MichoelR where can I get a Hebrew copy of the hesped

@Dude You, uh, have the wrong Brisker Rav and the wrong Lubavitcher Rebbe? And not in America? Also, "lots of witnesses to a positive relationship" is a far cry from the story you told, which I can imagine would offend a Brisker. Also, you haven't brought lots of witnesses, you brought one Chabad chasid. The story would be more believable if you found a "student of Reb Chaim Brisker" - mentioned in the story! - to tell it.

@Dude Basically you don't realize that you are reacting to the two stories in exactly the opposite way to how a Brisker talmid would react. You like the one you like, so you believe it without question, and you dislike the other story so you're demanding proofs. A Brisker talmid might very well say exactly the opposite.

@MichoelR lots of excuses and slander in your rambling responses

@Yoreinu Is this it? Again from R' Moshe Schuchman https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/186779/p/-1/t/1/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c

@Dude I don't think so. I'm just describing what I think is happening.

It is documented in על התורה ועל התמורה, p. 104:

הרב מבריסק: כשקרא את שיחתו הראשונה “באתי לגני” – תש”י עם עלותו על כס
האדמורו”ת, התבטא (בפני הגר”ד פינקל) “דער מישוגינער רעט זיך איין אז ער
איז משיח”! ואנו עוד נסבול ממנו בעתיד.

A better translation would be: "This meshuggeneh is saying about himself that he is mashiach, and we will suffer more from this."

Why not just quote the original? No one knows if the inflammatory language is actually his or is yours

Who wrote this book?

R Shach shared similar sentiments. We all know you can't criticize the Rebbe online, everyone knows the rules.

@deuternomy thanks for the edit. :)

Google translates that quote to "The meshugena saves himself and he is the Messiah". Where are you getting "we will suffer more from this"?

@DoubleAA Google is wrong. Maybe the typo I fixed contributed.

@DoubleAA See the last line.

You translated "עוד" wrong. In the context written it means something like - we will still suffer from him in the future

Are you sure the last line was also said by the Brisker Rav? It's in Hebrew and not Yiddish.

@Yoreinu That is what I meant.

@Harel13 I noticed that too. I assume it is and it was translated because the book is in Hebrew. The first line was said in Yiddish to capture the feel of what the Brisker Rav said.

Can anyone clarify the provenance of the book על התורה ועל התמורה and of the material quoted in their book. As far as I can see none of the quotes are sourced, including the Brisker Rav ztz”l quote the subject of this question.

@EdwardB Yeah. This may be the main source and it isn't very much.

i wonder if using the word מישוגינער or words like it about other rabbis was characteristic of the Brisker Rav. If not (together with the lack of any source other than the book על התורה ועל התמורה would be an indication that the words quoted may not have been spoken by the Brisker Rav.

@EdwardB The book says the source of the quote is Rav Dovid Finkel. He was considered a close student of the Brisker Rav. See here: https://mishpacha.com/leader-of-the-lions-rav-leib-malin/

@N.T. Thank you. Please excuse my ignorance, was (is?) Rav Dovid Finkel a well-known figure?

@EdwardB I've seen him mentioned elsewhere.

The way I heard the story there was no name calling. I think the name calling was added by others to further their machloikes. Is there a reliable sefer which printed the maaseh at the time it happened?
